Destructuring an array of variables from an unknown object
I just have a question if it is possible to destructure an object using an array of variables.  I know it is possible if you know the name of the Object Keys but if you do not know the keys of the object (e.g. from an API) can this be done? Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.
const names = {
a: 'peter',
b: 'jane',
c: 'sam',
};

let vals = Object.keys(names);
console.log(vals);
// const { a, b, c } = names;
[vals] = names;
console.log(a, b, c);


But how would you do console.log(a, b, c); or use the variables a, b, c, ... in any way if you don't know that those keys/names exist? I mean, either you know these keys exist, and you can create the corresponding variables, or you don't know them, and you need to iterate over the keys anyway.

You can transform an object with Object.entities that allows to handle both keys and values.

Method 1:


const names = {
  a: 'peter',
  b: 'jane',
  c: 'sam',
};

var vals = [];
for (var key in names) { // iterate through each key value pair
  vals.push(names[key]); // add value to array
}

console.log(vals);



Method 2:


const names = {
      a: 'peter',
      b: 'jane',
      c: 'sam',
    };

var vals = Object.values(names);
console.log(vals);




Besides that, it is unclear why you suggest using a loop instead of Object.values(names). And if this is actually what the OP is looking for, then the question should be closed as a duplicate.

I never use let for compatibility reasons

There are actually tons of reasons why not to use var.. Aside from this silly discussion, your answer has nothing to do with destructing an object into multiple variables.

I disagree; there's nothing wrong with using var. As for the question itself, I've placed the values into elements of an array, which is my understanding of what OP was after.

If you want to get a value of list, there is a two way.
let nameValueList = []
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(names)) {
   nameValueList.push(value)
}
console.log(nameValueList); // ["peter", "jane", "sam"]

or
console.log(Object.values(names)) // ["peter", "jane", "sam"]

